# Looping through JSON array of data to create objects of organized data is pushing the value into the correct spot but into all of the objects

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

I've got a JSON response of time card entries that I'm trying to process with a function that first loops through the response and adds an employee object to an `employeeList` object for each employee, with the employee's name being the key. At the same time, a `projectList` object gets populated with key values taken from all of the time card entries, then adds this projectList object as a value to each date in a `dateList` object. Each `datelist` date has the full list of projects.

The JSON response is then looped through once more, to take that entry and add it to an array of entries for that project within the correct date for the correct employee. It's working, and the time card entry JSON object is being put in the correct day and correct project, but it's doing this for each employee in the `employeeList` instead of only the employee who's time card entry it is.

Below is the code I have.

```
let employeeList = {};
let projectList = {};

let dateList = {
    "2023-02-26": {},
    "2023-02-27": {},
    "2023-02-28": {},
    "2023-03-01": {},
};

class Employee {
    constructor(name, qbid) {
        this.startdate = '2023-02-26';
        this.enddate = '2023-03-01';
        this.fname = "";
        this.lname = "";
        this.name = name;
        this.qbid = qbid;
        this.timeentries = [];
    }
}

function processData(res) {
    //create employee objects for each employee timeentry[155].value is a name text value "Last, First"
    res.data.forEach((timeentry) => {
        employeeList[timeentry[155].value] = new Employee(timeentry[155].value,timeentry[160].value);
    //add all projects to projectList obj.
        projectList[timeentry[18].value] = {
            projectname: timeentry[18].value,
            projectid: timeentry[17].value,
            timecards: []
        }
    });
//add projectList to each date in dateList
    for (key in dateList) {
        dateList[key] = projectList
    }
//add dateList with projectLists to employee.timeentries
    for (key in employeeList) {
        employeeList[key].timeentries = dateList;
    }
    
//add time entry objects to employee,date,project     
    res.data.forEach(timeentry => {
        employeeList[timeentry[155].value].timeentries[timeentry[23].value][timeentry[18].value].timecards.push(timeentry)
    })
}
```

The Employee Object ends up like this:

```
Last, First: {
     fname: 'First',
     lname: 'Last',
     timeentries: {
          2023-03-01: {
                project1:{
                     timecards:{[JSON Object]}
                     },
                project2:{
                     timecards:{[JSON Object]}
                     }
           },
           2023-03-02: {
                project1:{
                     timecards:{[JSON Object]}
                     },
                project2:{
                     timecards:{[JSON Object]}
                     }
           }
    }
}
```

The time entry is getting added to every employee's project and date, instead of just one employee. As a result, each employee ends up with all other employees' timecards in their own for that project on that date.

I don't understand why, since the last forEach should be using the 'Last, First' name value in [155].value from the json timeentry object, then going to the employeeList['Last, First'] object down through the time entries, to the date and to the project. Any insight would be mostly appreciated.

Comment: You're adding the same `projectList` object to all elements of `dateList`, and the same `dateList` to all employees. You need to make copies.

Comment: Thank you. When those are added, should it be something like dateList[key] = structuredClone(projectList)

Comment: Using structuredClone() worked and the results are as desired; thanks again Barmar.